# Can an array of objects be passed as context through a segue to a WatchKit Interface Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

In the sending `InterfaceController`:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
    if segueIdentifier == "FooSegue" {
        return self.FooList
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the receiving `InterfaceController`:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    if let fooList = context as? [Foo] {
        self.fooList = fooList
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `fooList` is empty when I examine it in the debugger.  I double checked the return value of `contextForSegueWithIdentifier` and it appears correct.

Comment: You are using a segue instead of `-presentControllerWithName`, correct? In the receiving controller, does `context` hold any value? Are you sure `-contextForSegueWithIdentifier` isn't returning nil? Your code looks correct, so it must be something else that's wrong.

Comment: @Schemetrical Definitely using `segue`, hooked it up as a `push` segue from a `button` to the new `InterfaceController`.  Also, it definitely isn't returning `nil` from the sending controller; I double checked with the debugger.

Comment: You need to double check if this condition is true or not : segueIdentifier == "FooSegue".

Comment: @DH14-SL I stepped through it using the debugger; it was true.

Comment: Have you tried passing FOO as an NSDictionary instead?